# Check if items in an array are the same in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a problem that seems simple, but I can't seem to get my head around the solution.

I have an array that looks like this `["foobar", "foo", "bar", "foobar"]` I want to write a method that checks the elements of the array and joins the two that are different. So the resulting array would be `["foobar", "foobar", "foobar"]`

I have tired the following, but I get an array of numbers, not strings.

```

```
array = %w(foobar foo bar foobar)
@i = 0
array.map do |item|
  if item != array[i+1]
    item + array[@i+1]
  else
    item
  end
  i += 1
end
```

```

Comment: If you have `["foobar", "foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar"] ` then ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting numbers in your array is `i+=1` is returning a number, so that is what ends up in your resulting array. What you want to do is create an iterator that contains an index and then map on that:

```
array.each_with_index.map do |item, i|
  if item != array[i + 1]
    item + array[i + 1]
  else
    item
  end
end
```

That won't actually give you the result you want, though, since for your example array you'll get `['foobar', 'foobar', 'barfoobar', 'foobar']`.

The best approach will depend on the actual expected contents of the arrays. For your sample array, I'd do:

```
array.each_with_index.map do |item, i|
  if item != array[i + 1] && array[i + 1] != array.max
    item + array[i + 1]
  elsif item != array[i + 1]
    nil
  else
    item
  end
end.compact
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I forgot that ruby returns the last line. When I run that, i am getting `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`. Is this because `item` is nil on the first iteration?

Comment: I imagine it has to do with what `array[i + 1]` is when `array[i]` is the last element. You'll have to account for that, too.